# Flow Condition for entry

Tags: visual-workflow, conditional, system-admin, entry-criteria

Need help for the below entry condition in the flow as my entry condition is not matching with the expectation.

Object:  Case Comment

Condition for Entry:

1. Case Comment parent record type should be any of from  -  ABC or DEF
2. AND - IsPublished  =  true
3. Owner Profile Should not be equal to  - AABCGH

Above all condition should be in AND.

tried below approach:

```
AND(OR({!$Record.Parent.RecordType.DeveloperName}  = 'ABC',{!$Record.Parent.RecordType.DeveloperName}  = 'DEF')&&{!$Record.IsPublished = true}{!$Record.Parent.Owner:User.Profile.Name}<>'AABCGH')`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put in double `=` to evaluate the RecordType Name. There was also a syntax error where you forgot the comma.

There is a button `Check Syntax` that you can press that checks your formula and shows any error messages that can help you correct any mistakes in your formula.

[image]

```
AND(
    OR({!$Record.Parent.RecordType.DeveloperName}=='ABC',
       {!$Record.Parent.RecordType.DeveloperName}=='DEF'
      ),
    {!$Record.IsPublished},
    {!$Record.Parent.Owner: User.Profile.Name}<>'AABCGH'
   )
```

Comment: Hi Getting syntax error  :- Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'   tried multiple places closing the bracket

Comment: @Shekher remember to remove all the spaces from the formula when you copy/paste it from here